# I am currently using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS with Linux 5.4.0-65 generic and I am having a minor issue with the back ups

Tags: backup

I get a message saying it was unable to back up /home/graham/.config/enchant and also /home/graham/.dbus. Can anyone help me resolve this issue please?

Comment: Where does this message come from? Please include complete log or command output of what you're trying to do.

Comment: You might find [this reference](https://www.fosslinux.com/14004/how-to-setup-files-and-folders-backup-on-ubuntu.htm) useful regarding backups - in particular hidden directories and files which begin with a dot.

Comment: Hi @Artur, I have my PC doing a scheduled weekly backup using Deja Dup and when it's finished it leaves me the messages above. It has done this for every backup. I'm sorry but I am reasonably competent with a PC but I try to use built-in things rather than trying my hand using Terminal commands so I'm afraid I really don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: I found this existing question that seems a bit similar: https://askubuntu.com/questions/970270/how-to-make-deja-dup-behave

Comment: Hi @Artur, thank you for your input. I have read through the reference you suggested but what he has done is not something I am able to do (incomplete instructions) However with a bit more searching I have read that perhaps deja-dup is not supposed to be saving those files anyway. So I am going to just leave it alone and hope everything is OK. So consider this question answered. Thanks for your help Artur.